# Play scala: How to call Controller Action method from a scheduler code?

Tags: scala, playframework

In my Play Scala app I need to reuse the Controller Action code (which is actually a REST API as defined in routes file):

conf/routes file:

```
POST   /saveuserdata     controllers.thirdpartyapi.SaveUserDataController.saveUserData
```

SaveUserDataController.scala:

```
class SaveUserDataController extends Controller {
    def saveUserData = Action.async {
          //code which call a third party API (using WS) and returns Ok
          //or InternalServerError
    }
}
```

ApplicationTimer.scala:

```
val onceCancellable: Cancellable = system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(0.seconds) {
   //call above Action method here and test for return status code
   if (status == 200) {
       println("Success: API returned 200 OK")
   } else {
       println("Failure: API returned failure status")
   }
   onceCancellable.cancel()
}
```

How do I call a controller Action method from another place ?

Comment: What you can do is extract that functionality into some other method and call that method in Action.async and place that method inside a trait which this controller extends and the other place from where you are calling also extends ! And hence you can get the functionality in both the places !

Comment: Calling a controller method from outside of the controller is not an ideal design choice. You could put your scheduler method in another controller method and Redirect the original request to the Scheduler method!

Comment: The scheduler code runs independent from the API i.e. scheduler calls the same API on a certain time of the day (keeps polling every 5 mins). The REST API is for external users. So there is no way for me to redirect the call to scheduler.

Comment: Actually the best way that I wanted to try was calling the REST API or its associated route "controllers.thirdpartyapi.routes. SaveUserDataController.saveUserData" from inside the scheduler code. I tried but it returns me play.api.mvc.Call instead of the Result of call to controller Action method. When a REST API is called by the client to Play server, Play automatically instantiates Controller and calls its Action. I thought I could recreate the same behaviour when I call it from another place.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to call the controller action using an HTTP request instead of extracting the common code to another class/method that is easier to reuse in your scheduler?

Comment: I wanted to try this way so that first, it makes the code quite neat and manageable. Any developer who looks at the code in future understands immediately the intent behind this approach. Second, it would help in using the same approach where one needs to call an action from another action.